# Is authentication done by IIS before HttpApplication.AddOnAuthenticateRequestAsync event is raised

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication

I am a newbie in IIS and authentication/authorization world. I am working on implementing a user token session cache for users that have been authenticated once (with TTL for entry) in our application. I see that events can raised on AddOnBeginRequestAsync and AddOnAuthenticateRequestAsync in HttpModule. we are using windows authentication. I have 3 questions in this regard :

1. Has the request already being authenticated when the BeginEventhandler for AddOnAuthenticateRequestAsync is raised ?
2. How can I ask IIS to forgo authentication for some users (using the auth cache that I generate). I can perform this check in the BeginEventHandler for BeginRequest.
3. For telemetry about aggressive users with bad credentials, How can I get the username for failed authenticated requests. Will I be able to fetch this information from LogRequest event ?

It would be great if you can point articles/docs to read as well.

thanks

Comment: #1 - No, BeginEventHandler for AddOnAuthenticateRequestAsync is called before the authentication. #2 - This could be done by setting the HttpContext.Items[AuthSession] object.